# Environment.SpecialFolders in Silverlight 4 on Mac

Tags: silverlight, macos, silverlight-4.0

Silverlight 4 running with elevated permissions provides access to certain special folders in the file system.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder(VS.95).aspx

These work great on Windows, but what do they map to on Mac OSX systems?

My application needs to access "My Documents". Will this map somewhere sensible on the mac?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but with a little trick.
You can create a file on windows even the containing folder does not exist, but on OS X your have to create the directory first. If not you will get an exception.
My code is as follow:

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath);  // Not necessary on windows
FileStream newFs = File.Create(dirFile);
newFs.Close();
newFs.Dispose();
```

On OS X the "My Documents" folder is here:

```
/Users/[UserName]/Documents
```